# Position of axis label / tick in Recharts

Tags: recharts

I am using ReCharts (1.0.0-beta.10) in react.

The code I am using to render the chart is:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={100}>
    <BarChart data={data} layout="vertical" stackOffset="expand">
      <YAxis dataKey="title" type="category" axisLine={false} tick={{ fill: 'white', scaleToFit: true, textAnchor: 'middle' }} />
      <XAxis type="number" axisLine={false} tick={false} />
      <Bar dataKey="votingFor" stackId="a" fill={colourPalette.voting.for}>
        <LabelList dataKey="votingFor" />
      </Bar>
      <Bar dataKey="votingAgainst" stackId="a" fill={colourPalette.voting.against}>
        <LabelList dataKey="votingAgainst" />
      </Bar>
      <Bar dataKey="votingUnsure" stackId="a" fill={colourPalette.voting.unsure}>
        <LabelList dataKey="votingUnsure" />
      </Bar>
    </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

The result is:
[image]

What can I do to only have the chart start after the end of the label
(the label size may differ)?